# NameResolutionFailure with Azure Storage Unity UWP app (works in Player)

Tags: c#, azure, unity-game-engine, uwp, azure-storage

I have a Hololens app that should load data from Azure Storage. When using the [WindowsAzure.Storage package converted to a unitypackage](https://github.com/BrianPeek/AzureSDKs-Unity), I can load data when using the Unity Player and when testing with a normal 2D XAML UWP app, I can also load data using that API on the Hololens, however, when debugging the IL2CPP project, I get a "WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure" ([full log](https://pastebin.com/wZcmyPDj)).

Here are the steps to build a simplified testing project:

- Open Unity 2018.2 (I use 2018.2.14f, 2018.2 is necessary for using
  https, which is apparently necessary for connecting to Azure)
- Set .NET version of Unity Project to 4.x, because the Azure Storage API uses await/async, I used IL2CPP as backend. The .NET backend gives errors about some Newtonsoft.JSON functions not being found, which might be what is causing me problems? Assets/Plugins/Newtonsoft.Json.dll exists and references .NET v4.0.30319.

> Error: method
>   `System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1
>   Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject::LoadAsync(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader,System.Threading.CancellationToken)`
>   doesn't exist in target framework. It is referenced from
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.dll at System.Void
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.ODataErrorHelper/d__2::MoveNext().

- Create an empty game object called ImageGrid at (0, 0, 2)
- Import the script PopulateImageGrid.cs below to the project and attach it to the ImageGrid
- Create a prefab from a 1*1*0.1 cube and set the public field Image Grid Tile of the Image Grid game object to that prefab
- Delete Assets/Plugins/Microsoft.CSharp.dll as Unity complains about it existing twice
- Build as UWP, load the built project in Visual Studio and start with Release and x86 selected (or deploy to Hololens)

Here's the PopulateImageGrid.cs. Feel free to connect with the account details given in the code, as it's a free account without sensitive data.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
// using UnityEditor.PackageManager;
using UnityEngine;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.File;
using System;

public class PopulateImageGrid : MonoBehaviour {

    public Transform ImageGridTile;

    async void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("In PopulateImageGrid.Start()");
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(@"DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;FileEndpoint=https://meshiconstorage.file.core.windows.net;AccountName=meshiconstorage;AccountKey=2Myeg/WUowehkrAY8Lgl361xxylfkMdITrVapKKVPyo9bVFqN6/uD1S66CB4oTPnnWncLubiVjioBUIT+4utaw==");
        CloudFileClient cloudFileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
        string shareName = "meshicon-share1";
        var cloudFileShare = cloudFileClient.GetShareReference(shareName);
        CloudFileDirectory rootDirectory = cloudFileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference();
        var fileDirectory = rootDirectory.GetDirectoryReference("images");

        FileContinuationToken token = null;

        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        const int width = 32;
        const int height = 32;
        do
        {
            FileResultSegment frs = await fileDirectory.ListFilesAndDirectoriesSegmentedAsync(token);
            foreach (var result in frs.Results)
            {
                Debug.Log("In loop with " + result.ToString());
                Vector3 position = new Vector3(col++ * 0.13f - 0.39f, row * 0.13f - 0.26f, 0f);
                Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.identity;
                Transform gridTile = Instantiate(ImageGridTile);
                gridTile.transform.parent = gameObject.transform;
                gridTile.localPosition = position;
                gridTile.localRotation = rotation;
                if (col > 6)
                {
                    row++;
                    col = 0;
                }
                byte[] imgData = new byte[10000];
                int size = await ((CloudFile)result).DownloadToByteArrayAsync(imgData, 0);
                Debug.Log("Downloaded to byte[]");
                Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(width, height);
                byte[] realImgData = new byte[size];
                Array.Copy(imgData, realImgData, size);
                texture.LoadImage(imgData);
                gridTile.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material.mainTexture = texture;
            }
        } while (token != null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick was to wait until after a 30-second timeout the error message of a NameResolutionFailure appeared, which made it apparent to me that I should activate internet permissions in the appxmanifest.